# Can duplicate tables per object provide an advantage in large data environments?

Tags: sql, database, structure, modeling

Consider a simple website that has billions of users, all registered with a username and password. And they can post messages on this website. You are able to look up an user and then see all that user's posts.

I would design this structure as such:

```
user (id, name, password)
1 arne <pass>
2 jeff <pass>
...
99999999999999999 erik <pass>

post (id, message)
1 hello
2 test
3 hey
...

post_user (puid, postid, userid)
1 1 1 
2 2 1 
3 3 2
```

By which I could then simply show all posts by looking up **arne**'s id (1), joining this with the post_user table and posts table and get all his posts.

Now when I picture millions of messages for millions of users, I imagine the **post** and **post_user** table getting pretty huge. So I was wondering if the following model could provide useful in a really large environment. Say you were to create a unique posts table for every user:

```
user (id, name, password)
1 arne <pass>
2 jeff <pass>
...
99999999999999999 erik <pass>

post1 (id, message)
1 hello
2 test

post2 (id, message)
3 hey
```

Then you could get all the posts by one user by finding the id, and doing a **select from ("post" + userid)**, meaning you would have a much smaller table to look through.

Could working like this prove beneficial? A problem I could think of would be that you would have about a million post1, post2, ...,  postx tables that each take up storage and altering them would be a disaster.

Comment: Have you considered to use [NoSQL](http://goo.gl/kNQQUL) data bases?. You would avoid the JOIN of big tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how well this will work.,
but if you say you have a specified number of length for the post yes you can.

you can have two tables :

1. login -- id, username, password
2. messages -- id, post_data, date_time_stamp.

so when you query you can do something like this

select * from messages where id==//some id you generate

this will listout all the post a person has posted.

or

if you want a person's post on a specified date..

(considering you have the same kind of date_time_stamp in your UI also)

you can query like
select * from messages where id=="" and date=="";

similarly for time also you can try...

Cheers